# oData - how to use filter for specific odata.type

Tags: odata

### My oData query is as follow.

http://localhost:21005/api/v1/Devices?$expand=Jobs

### My oData JSON response (in Postman's Pretty format) is as follow.

```
{
"@odata.context": "http://localhost:21005/api/v1/$metadata#Devices",
_"value": [
    {
        "Id": "abc03c74-8697-49ec-85e6-6444112d0336",
        "TimeOffset": 0,
        "TimeOffsetMode": "Unmanaged",
        "Jobs": [
        {
           "@odata.type": "#VT.Api.Models.GetDataJob",
           "Id": "ba07d50a-f17d-4c65-b3cf-f3e03d1ba1cf"
        },
        {
           "@odata.type": "#VT.Api.Models.GetDataProfilerJob",
           "Id": "5aa9c046-e4f2-44de-b932-16c06b86b084"
        },
        {
           "@odata.type": "#VT.Api.Models.GetDeviceConfigurationJob",
           "Id": "d7dc0ac5-1f89-4356-aaa8-9ac40353e1af"
        }
    }
    {
        "Id": "d42ac1f0-1261-4100-8391-013a226ff25f",
        "TimeOffset": 0,
        "TimeOffsetMode": "Unmanaged",
        "Jobs": [ ]
    }
}
```

---

Now, I want to query for only specific "@oData.type"
For example, I just want all the "Jobs" whose data type is "#VT.Api.Models.GetDataJob" ("@odata.type": "#VT.Api.Models.GetDataJob"). What kind of filter or query should I use?

Answer (score 2):

The query should be:
http://localhost:21005/api/v1/Devices?$expand=Jobs($filter=isof('VT.Api.Models.GetDataJob'))

but as Brad said, IsOf has not been implemented in webapi odata v4.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current spec, the correct way would be to apply a type filter to the expand expression, e.g.:

```
http://host/service/Orders?$expand=Customer/Model.VipCustomer
```

or, using your example,

```
http://localhost:21005/api/v1/Devices?$expand=Jobs/VT.Api.Models.GetDataJob
```

Please note that this will return all devices, expand their `Jobs` association, and only add `GetDataJob` instances to the resulting association sets. If you only want to query devices that *have* `GetDataJob` instances, you will need to see if you can use [lambdas](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793847) with type filters.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803582/odata-expand-on-derived-types) and [OData Version 4.0 Part 2: URL Conventions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793786)

Answer (score 0):

According to the OData spec you should be able to use the "IsOf" function to accomplish this. However, I don't believe this has been implemented yet in WebApi OData v4 (assuming that's what you're using):

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/185