# oData $expand on Derived Types

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am having challenges with odata query to get derived type:

{{Url}}/odata/resource?$expand=derivedType

See this [link](http://www.odata.org/blog/enhancing-odata-support-for-querying-derived-types/) which gives options like 
~/People/OfType('Employee')(41)/Manager or ~/People!Employee which didn't work.

Is this supported with Asp.Net Web Api 2 with EF6? What would be the query?

Answer (score 2):

This is an exerpt from OData 4.0 convention docs:

> Any resource path or path expression identifying a collection of
>   entities or complex type instances can be appended with a path segment
>   containing the qualified name of a type derived from the declared type
>   of the collection. The result will be restricted to instances of the
>   derived type and may be empty.  Any resource path or path expression
>   identifying a single entity or complex type instance can be appended
>   with a path segment containing the qualified name of a type derived
>   from the declared type of the identified resource. If used in a
>   resource path and the identified resource is not an instance of the
>   derived type, the request will result in a 404 Not Found response. If
>   used in a path expression that is part of a Boolean expression, the
>   type cast will evaluate to null.  Example 30: entity set restricted to
>   VipCustomer instances
>
> **http://host/service/Customers/Model.VipCustomer** 
>   
> Example 31: entity
>   restricted to a VipCustomer instance, resulting in 404 Not Found if
>   the customer with key 1 is not a VipCustomer
>
> **http://host/service/Customers/Model.VipCustomer(1)
>   http://host/service/Customers(1)/Model.VipCustomer** 
>   
> Example 32: cast
>   the complex property Address to its derived type DetailedAddress, then
>   get a property of the derived type
>
> **http://host/service/Customers(1)/Address/Model.DetailedAddress/Location**
>   
> Example 33: filter expression with type cast; will evaluate to null
>   for all non-VipCustomer instances and thus return only instances of
>   VipCustomer
>
> **http://host/service/Customers?$filter=Model.VipCustomer/PercentageOfVipPromotionProductsOrdered gt
>   80**
> Example 34: expand the single related Customer only if it is an
>   instance of Model.VipCustomer. For to-many relationships only
>   Model.VipCustomer instances would be inlined,
>
> **http://host/service/Orders?$expand=Customer/Model.VipCustomer**

Answer (score 1):

The information in that blog post is out of date. The official OData specifications are available at http://www.odata.org/documentation/.

In OData v4, you can [filter by derived type](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398088) by appending the fully-qualified name of the derived type to the resource URI path. For example, `GET http://host/Employees/MyService.Manager` would retrieve the subset of Employees who are also Managers (assuming Manager is derived from Employee type). The prefix `MyService` in the last path segment is the OData namespace in which the `Manager` type is defined.

You can also filter by derived type when [expanding a navigation property](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398162) by appending the fully-qualified name of the derived type to the name of the property in an `$expand` clause. For example, `GET http://host/Companies('Acme')?$expand=Employees/MyService.Manager` would retrieve the Company named Acme with all Managers expanded inline.

Comment: Tried $expand=resource/namespace.resourceDerivedType. I am getting 400 bad request. {
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Found a path traversing multiple navigation properties. Please rephrase the query such that each expand path contains only type segments and navigation properties."
  }
}

Comment: I've answered your question about the format of queries using derived types. If you have a specific problem, please post another question with code samples.