# OData v4 $orderby on a child derived property

Tags: odata, odata-v4

I have the following scenario:

```
public class Stay
{
    [Contained]
    public Guest PrimaryGuest {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Guest
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
}

public class EntityGuest : Guest
{
     public string EntityName {get;set;}
}

public class PersonGuest : Guest
{
     public string SurName {get;set;}

     public string GivenName {get;set;}
}
```

When querying for the stays, I wish to order by a PersonGuest/SurName.

I know how to order by a child property:  `[URL]/Stays?$expand=PrimaryGuest&$orderby=PrimaryGuest/ID` - but how would I order by on a child property that is derived? Is it even possible? I could not determine it by the OData documentation - it wasn't at least called out for contained entities.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me a lot in a similar scenario: [oData $expand on Derived Types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40112499/1690217)

Basically you can 'Cast' any complex or entity typed property in your query by adding a forward slash and the qualified name of the *model* type, using the namespace you have defined for your model, not the .Net full type name.

`[URL]/Stays?$expand=PrimaryGuest&$orderby=PrimaryGuest/ModelNamespace.PersonGuest/Surname`

If you are unsure of the model namespace, look at the model builder code, or use something similar to this:

```
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "MyAppModel";
```

Then your URL should look like this:

`[URL]/Stays?$expand=PrimaryGuest&$orderby=PrimaryGuest/MyAppModel.PersonGuest/Surname`